# How to convert from tons to kilonewtons?

Tags: thrust

How do a go from a thrust of `66.28 t` to kilonewtons?

```
thrust:  66.28 t
isp:     237.2 s
burn:    34 s
```

These values are from [spacelaunchreport](http://www.spacelaunchreport.com/ariane4.html) under Vehicle Components, for the Ariane 4 PAP solid booster.

Comment: Are those metric tons, in other words `1 ton = 1000 kg?` In that case, they might be referenced to standard gravitational acceleration `g = 9.80665 m/s^2` and if that is true, and *only if that is true*, you would multiply tons by 1000 to get kg-equivalent, then by `g` to get Newtons (`kg m /s^2`), or just multiply tons by `g` to get kiloNewtons directly. Always pay close attention to the units, they will help suggest how to use your values. You can also read this: http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication330e2008.pdf

Comment: Someone has down voted your question, probably because it is not clear, and you haven't included enough information really. (They should have left a comment as well). Can you explain where these numbers are coming from?

Comment: @uhoh - Thanks. I added a bit more detail (where I got the numbers from).

Comment: @uhoh - Your comment is correct, I'd checked with some other numbers where I knew the kN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the figure appears to be in metric tons-force, so the conversion factor to kN is ["standard gravity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravity)†, ~9.81 m/s<sup>2</sup>. 66.28 tons-force is therefore 650 kN, which is the figure I see on [Wikipedia for the Ariane 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_4) PAP solid booster.

† Not to be confused with the [*standard gravitational parameter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter).

Comment: Being (apparently) the "[resident stickler](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41863664#41863664)" it might be better to just quote the correct value for [standard gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravity) since "gravity at Earth's surface" actually varies by roughly a percent from place to place. It even has an [ISO thingy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_80000-3#Units_of_time,_speed_and_acceleration)!

Comment: As the converted value came out suspiciously close to the suspiciously round figure of 650kN, I suspect that three decimal places is overkill to begin with. I'm idly considering formulating a question about uncertainty in engine thrust figures, but haven't decided if I care enough about it.

Comment: I still believe the correct answer is to multiply metric tons by exactly `9.80665 m/s2` the standard value, and if an example is found somewhere which suggests a different value was used, it means that they did it wrong.

Comment: The correct answer is not to pretend you have significant figures that you don't actually have, but I'll meet you halfway on terminology.

Comment: That applies to how one would *display a result*, but not the underlying procedure that one should use when performing the calculation, or especially when answering how others should perform the calculation. "Pre-rounding" before you are done is not a good ideal. Someone might have more digits in the future.

Comment: I don't know how to get it across to you that "exactly 9.80665" IS "approximately 9.81". ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I'm just replying to the use of the word "pretending". My meaning is that the correct answer to this "how to" question is to multiply by the correct number. Using all available digits during the calculation is the correct procedure, there is no "pretending" in doing so. Subsequent calculations might involve subtraction of two large numbers for example. The edit looks good (as does your sketch!)